# Create curved lines by font

Tags: font-design, fontlab-studio

I'm trying to create a font to produce different curved lines similar the below example (*curved lines with different shapes*), and want to use it through general word processing programs (e.g. MS Word). However I'm not sure about the starting point since this does not obey general typographical metrics.

[image]

I'd like to know is it possible to create such a font **at all** (I own FontLab 5)?! I also about thinking to buy some similar font at first, if you could suggest me one?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible with font creation software such as Fontlab or Fontographer, or Glyph, or BirdFont.. or any of them, really.

Fonts are merely a collection of symbols, what those symbols are is irrelevant. This is why you see fonts which are pictograms, like Wingdings.

Answer (score 0):

For sure it is possible. but such shape will be hard to compose due to the beginning and the end of every pulse.
you have to compose all possibilities and in deep 2 and 3 and 4 as much as you pulses ends.

In you example a pulse is starting in the middle level and ends by the second one, that's mean the next pulse must start at the second level. Then the two character will shape a special new one which will be -for the system- considered as a single new character and if you start a new character after it, then you are starting a new composition between 3 (characters/symbols) ... and so one.

compositions in fonts is easy to do when it come between two or three characters but making a composition for more than that with its alternatives I think it will be so so hard.

you have no choice that starting and ending the pulse in the same level. and in that case it will be so fake.

I hoped that I could explained it well.

the next example will show you a comparison between your original pulses and how you could get when not considering compositions.

[image]